# Trying to run a test suite in Eclipse Force.com, but I am getting authentication error

Tags: force.com, eclipse, ide, test-suite

I can save metadata and execute anonymous apex via my Force.com project, so presumably my login credentials and token are working, but I receive an error when trying to run a test suite that I have saved locally and to the server.

[image: Authentication error when trying to run test suite]

Comment: It's possible that Eclipse wiped out your password for whatever reason (I've seen it happen). Check your project's Force.com settings.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I turns out my run configuration setting being used wasn't right. It was pointing to a different project with different credentials.

Answer (score 0):

My **Run Configuration** for **Apex Test** was pointing to a different org. I needed to update it, and the test suite ran fine.

[image]